# Transporterfleet not blocking eachother ANYLOGIC

Tags: anylogic

In my model I've a path-guided transporter fleet, but when they are close to eachother they are blocking eachother, since this is not the scope of my model (I want them just to override eachother ) is there a way to disable this option. I've already tried to set minimum distance to obstacle very low or use very small dimensions (see figure) but everything seems not to work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key aspect of Material-Handling transporters is to apply that spatial blocking.

If you do not want it, use moving resources from the Process modelling library. They act the same but do not have spatial awareness. However, they also cannot do the free-space navigation. Path-guided works but not applying path-specific constraints.

So it is a trade-off. The process-library resources also require much less computational power...

Comment: also the process modelling library can not make use of lifts right?

Comment: nope. But you can mix'n'match, these libraries work together very well :)